# Associated Product Weight

Tags: products, product-association

I have set up my store using associated products and had the weight set to 0. I now want to add a weight to the products in my store, does this mean I will have to go through each product and its associated products individually adding a weight to them or is there a way that I can set the base product weight and it will then update the associated products weight automatically.

The reason I am asking is because I have roughly 20 products in my store at the moment which is manageable to manually update each weight but when you factor in the associated products it goes into the hundreds as you imagine.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can export your products via Import/Export.
Then remove all the columns except sku and weight and fill in the csv, then import it again choosing to merge with the existing products.
But this may not be what you need. You still have to fill in hundreds of wights, even if you see all of them in the page.

If the method above does not suit you, you can edit the 20 configurable products, add the weight then run this script that updates the simple products.

```
//retrieve the configurable products
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect('weight')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable'); 
foreach ($collection as $item) {
     //get simple product ids associated to the configurable one.
     $ids = $item->getUsedProductIds();
     //update the simple products weight.
     Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
         $ids, //ids of products to update
         array('weight'=>$item->getWeight()), //attributes to update
         0 //store id
     );
}
```

The risk on this approach is that if you have a simple product associated to 2 or more configurable products the simple product will get the weight of the last processed configurable product.
If you don't have overlapping simple products you should be fine.

You can even combine the 2 methods I described. Use the first one to change the configurable products weights and the second for the simple products.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, my best option will probably be exporting to a csv.